# Преобразование типов в C++

Tags: c++, типы-данных, преобразование

Как в C++ происходит преобразование типов при присвоении беззнаковому типу отрицательного числа или числа не из диапазона типа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При выполнении присваивания производится *преобразование* исходного значения  к типу переменной-приемника. Поведение определяется правилами таких преобразований.

- Переполнение при преобразовании в *беззнаковый* целый тип из *целых* типов (как знаковых, так и беззнаковых) обрабатывается по правилами модульной арифметики с модулем 2^N, где `N` количество значащих бит в целевом беззнаковом типе.
- Переполнение при преобразовании в *знаковый* целый тип из *целых* типов (как знаковых, так и беззнаковых) приводит к поведению, определяемому реализацией. Реализация в том числе имеет право в таких ситуациях выкидывать сигнал.
- Переполнение при преобразовании в *целый* тип из *плавающих* типов приводит к неопределенному поведению.
- Переполнение при преобразовании в *плавающий* тип приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: "обрабатывается по правилами модульной арифметики с модулем 2^N, где N количество значащих бит в целевом беззнаковом типе"
Можете объяснить как это? На примере желательно. Например, если я присваиваю unsigned char = -1 и unsigned char = 567.

Comment: Записываете число в двоичной системе исчисления (положительное в прямом коде, отрицательное в дополнительном), берете младшие N бит. Если unsigned char представляется 8 битами (скорее всего так и будет), то N = 8, и надо взять младшие 8 бит. -1 в дополнительном коде все единицы во всех битах, значит в результате у вас будет 255. 567->0010 0011 0111->0011 0111->55

Comment: @foreblack: "обрабатывается по правилами модульной арифметики с модулем 2^N" означает, что число заменяется на его остаток от деления на `2^N`. Деление при этом вполняется *Евклидово*, т.е с всегда неотрицательным остатком. Например, для типа `unsigned char` с 8 битами модуль будет равен 256. Поэтому число `-1` превратится в остаток от деления `-1` на `256` - это `255`. Число `567` превратится в остаток от деления `567` на `256` - это `55`.

Comment: @foreblack: Другими словами этот можно описать так: если исходное значение *отрицательно*, то к нему прибавлятеся `2^N` до тех пор, пока значение ни попадет в диапазон типа. Если исходное значение *положительно*, то из него вычитается `2^N` до тех пор, пока значение ни попадет в диапазон типа. `-1` превращается в `-1 + 256 = 255`. `-1000` превращается в `-1000 + 256 + 256 + 256 + 256 = 24`. `567` превращается в `567 - 256 - 256 = 55`.

Comment: Заметьте, кстати, что поведение *беззнаковых* типов не зависит от того, какой код используется для представления *знаковых* типов. На платформе, использующей *дополнительный* код, вышеописанная операция сводится к тому, что надо просто взять `N` последних битов представления числа в дополнительном коде (см. комментарий @outcast). Т.е. фактически никаких остатков вычислять не надо, все получается "само собой". А вот на некоей гипотетической платформе, использующей *обратный* или *прямой* код для знаковых чисел, преобразование знаковых к беззнаковым может потребовать явного вычисления остатка.

Comment: Разобрался. Только почему -1%256 = 255, а не -1? С евклидовым делением связано?

Comment: @foreblack: Да, именно так. Евклидово деление `a` на `b`, по определению, это разложение `a = qb + r`, где `q` - частное и `r` - остаток. При этом требуется, что `0 <= r < b`. Вот это последнее требование - остаток всегда неотрицателен - и является определяющим свойством Евклидова деления. Или, другими словами, частное в Евклидовом делении всегда округляется к *отрицательной бесконечности*.  Т.е. при делении `-1` на `256` получается частное `-1` с остатком `255`.

Comment: (При этом стоит заметить, что операторы `/` и `%` в языках С и С++ реализуют *не* Евклидово деление, а т.наз. Фортран-деление с округлением частного *к нулю*. Поэтому в С и С++ оператор `%` может давать отрицательный результат.)

Answer (score 2):

Данные преобразования описаны в разделе 4.7 Integral conversions стандарта C++. В этом разделе в отношении преобразования из знакового целочисленного типа в беззнаковый целочисленный тип написано

> 2 If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the
>   least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n
>   where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [
>   Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is
>   conceptual and **there is no change in the bit pattern** (if there is no
>   truncation). —end note ]

Что касается преобразования в знаковый целочисленный тип, то там же написано

> 3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width);
>   otherwise, **the value is implementation-defined.**

Если же объекты знаковых и беззнаковых целых чисел принимают участие в выражении, то сначала определяется их общий тип, чтобы вывести тип значения выражения, согласно правилам обычных арифметических преобразований. 
Например, согласно этим правилам если два целочисленных типа, беззнаковый и знаковый, имеют одинаковый ранг, то объект знакового типа преобразуется к беззнаковому типу.

Вот пример, на который не каждый программист сможет сходу ответить. 
Допустим у вас на машине `sizeof( long )` равняется `sizeof( int )`. Можно предположить, что оба эти выражения равны 4, хотя это не обязательно.
И имеются следующие объявления

```
unsigned int x = 0;
long y = 0;
```

Спрашивается: какой тип будет иметь выражение:)

```
x + y
```

Comment: Можно перевод английского текста?

Comment: @foreblack  Если вы хотите иметь дело с программированием, то вам следует учить английский.:) Вы можете перевести либо используя службу translate либо bing, либо google.. Например, если вы используете IE, то выделите текст, нажмите правую кнопку мыши и выберите пункт "Перевод с помощью Bing"

Comment: @foreblack  Например, во второй выдержке из стандарта написано, что "если тип назначения знаковый, то значение остается неизменным, если оно может быть представлено в типе назначения (и в размере битового поля). В противном случае значение зависит от реализации."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а какой тип будет иметь это выражение? И где в стандарте это описано? Компилятору не имеют единого мнения на этот счёт. Честно говоря мне понятно почему `long`(с точки зрения стандарта), понятно почему `unsigned long`(с точки зрения логики), но не понятно, что должно быть на самом деле.

Comment: @ixSci  Смотреть надо параграф №10 раздела "5 Expressions": "— Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type."