# Что такое "значения по модулю 16"?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Отрывок из статьи:

> Мы добавляем строку “Elephant”, первая функция даёт хэш код, равный
>   25425, а вторая 894346520. Всего у нас 16 бит, так что находим
>   значения по модулю 16. Итого, первый хэш 1, а второй 8. Выставляем
>   соответствующие биты.

Модуль это же вроде абс. значение числа... Я не могу понять что и как вычисляет автор что из 25425 получается 1 а из числа 894346520 получатся число 8?

Comment: модуль в программировании - это остаток от деления. Правда зачем тут берется по модулю 16 и как это соотносится с 16 битами для меня загадка. все таки по модулю 16 - это только 4 бита

Comment: Здесь имеется ввиду арифметика по модулю. Почитайте комментарии к ответу пользователя AnT в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437176/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c). Также можете посмотреть примеры кода для перевода чисел по модулю в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781552/262953).

Comment: @Mike: Да и в математике тоже

Comment: @Mike можно уточнить почему 16 это 4 бита? Ведь байт это 8 бит, т.е. можно сказать что здесь 2 байта. Но откуда 4 бита?

Comment: @fosh4455 Под "Значение по модулю 16" обычно понимается остаток от деления на 16. он может быть от 0 до 15 включительно. значения от 0 до 15 как раз в аккурат укладываются в 4 бита (2^4=16). Если имелось ввиду, что от значения надо оставить младшие 16 бит, то правильно было бы сказать "по модулю 2 в 16 степени"

Comment: @Mike а ну всмысле что 4 блока в каждом из которых может быть только 0 или 1 дадут 16 вариантов комбинаций? Поэтому здесь 4 бита...

Comment: @Mike это произвольная размерность которую он взял, её можно задать любой в зависимости от того сколько памяти у вас есть: 8, 32, миллион

Comment: Да, можно и так сказать. И кажется я понял что имел ввиду автор. Объем цитирования в вопросе все таки не достаточный. не сразу ясно откуда такая арифметика. И да, действительно по модулю просто 16. Он же потом выставляет один нужный бит. так что ему нужно значение до 0 до 15 что бы знать номер бита который поставить