# Почему моя программа при итерации с переменной типа size_t не работает (пишет "out of range"), а при типе int работает?

Tags: c++, int

Вот мой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string word;
    std::string palindrome;
    std::getline(std::cin, word);
    for (size_t i = word.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        palindrome.push_back(word[i]);
    }
    for (size_t c = 0; c < word.size(); c++) {
        if (word[c] == ' ') {
            word.erase(c, 1);
            c -= 1;
            
        }
        if (palindrome[c] == ' ') {
            palindrome.erase(c, 1);
            c -= 1;
        }
    }
    if (word == palindrome) {
        std::cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "NO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

в таком виде компилятор выдает ошибку. Однако если я использую в первом цикле for переменную типа int, все работает корректно. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А как вы представляете себе невыполнение условия `i>=0` для *беззнакового* типа? Для которого при значении 0 оператор `--` даст 0xFFFFFF....FF?

Comment: Компилятор выдал вам предупреждение о бессмысленном сравнении. Старайтесь не игнорировать предупреждения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ошибка ясна, но можете тогда, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему для итерации по строкам и векторам в основном используют тип size_t? И почему при значении 0 оператор -- даст 0xFFFFFF....FF?

Comment: `почему для итерации по строкам и векторам в основном используют тип size_t?` Потому что диапазон значений данного типа гарантированно достаточно широк, чтобы хранить индекс элемента массива. Например, если мы хотим обратиться к элементу с индексом `5'000'000'000`  в массиве из `6'000'000'000` элементов, то тип `int` (который обычно не более чем 32-битный) не годится в качестве индексной переменной, т.к. такое большое число не представимо типом `int`.

Comment: `И почему при значении 0 оператор -- даст 0xFFFFFF....FF?` Так как тип `std::size_t` беззнаковый, то точный математический результат декремента «упаковывается» в значение типа `std::size_t` по правилам [модулярной арифметики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437176/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c#comment456930_437211).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что size_t может принимать только неотрицательные значения. Т.е. после нуля идёт не -1, а максимально возможное size_t (18446744073709551615). Проще не париться с size_t и использовать int.